# finding php page in complicated structure

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, file-structure, filestructure

Is there an easy way to find the exact php page (including path) that a line of code appears in? For example, if I'm editing a wordpress theme with hundreds of php files in multiple nested folders, finding where, say, line 349 in the compiled source code appears in the file structure?

Comment: No! Compiled code doesn't have much meaning in PHP. And why would you want to or need to?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP language is interpreted and not compiled

Usually it will tell u the full path to the file when an error occurs .

if not you can display it by using :

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);

echo $path ;
```

Comment: Sry, I meant interpreted. But if there's not an error, and I'm looking for a specific line of code? I'm not trying to find where a particular page is in the file structure, I'm seaching for the page that line of code appears on. (And please speak to me like I'm an idiot, I don't know that much about php.)